# Getting error : Missing required argument $typeFactories

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, magento2.2.7

While Updating Magento 2.2.7 to 2.3.0 through composer when I am running below command

bin/magento setup:upgrade

I am getting below error :

```
Updating modules:
Missing required argument $typeFactories of Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\ElementFactory.

In AbstractFactory.php line 238:

  Missing required argument $typeFactories of Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\ElementFactory.
```

Any idea why this error pops-up on console?

Update :

When I run

php bin/magento -vvv setup:upgrade

```
Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:238
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:160
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:196
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:172
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:246
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:135
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:116
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1162
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:603
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:226
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:102
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/myproject/bin/magento:23
```

Comment: could you please add `-vvv` while executing the upgrade in order to get more information about which class causes that error?

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo I have updated question with -vvv